# genymotion failure install failed cpu api incompatible

Tags: genymotion

i recently started using genymotion i am newbie as they say, i figured out how to launch apps but the problem is the apps the i installed successfully are chat or programs apps only no games apps want to be installed on the virtual device i always get this message  failure install failed cpu api incompatible, i am using 2 pcs

both windows 7 x64 both got the same issue i will upload pics of the cmd commands i used

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF2gA.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8jEU.jpg

all i did i just installed these virtual devices

Galaxy S4-4.3 - API18 - 1080x1920
WXGA 10.1 Tablet - 4.3 - API 18 - 1280x800

so if u have any Questions or effective suggestions please help me :)

Best Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 27):

To solve INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on Genymotion, download following Zip files:

1. Arm Translation Installer
2. GApps

from this site http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

First drag&drop Arm Translation Installer zip file to virtual android machine

Press OK for the warning

Reboot virtual android machine

Drag&drop GApps to virtual android machine

(May took around 15 seconds to copy the files as GApps is around 350MB)

Reboot your virtual android machine.

Here you go, install your APK now!

---

Gapps for Lolipop download link:
http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/gapps/5.0/gapps-lp-20141109-signed.zip

Comment: Thanks JensG. ARM translation can be found from below xda link:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Answer (score 15):

Genymotion is supporting x86 only.

The error means that your apks does not support x86 architecture (probably only ARM).

You may be able to install it manually : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952