# i cant run my app in genymtion

Tags: android, genymotion

when i want to debug my app in genymotion, android studio give me this error:
[image]

but app is not install
and after ok :

```
 Failure details: Bundle[{android.content.pm.extra.STATUS=1, 
android.content.pm.extra.PACKAGE_NAME=ir.esfandune.mohsen, 
android.content.pm.extra.LEGACY_STATUS=-1, 
android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE=DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572239/1638739) you are getting this problem cause your app has a native libraries that can't be supported by the cpu architecture of GenyMotion, and this is true, I experienced this problem my self in GenyMotion when tried to launch an activity that calls a native library, despite I added a support to **arm** and **x86** but still didn't work, and you can't control cpu type through GenyMotion device settings as GenyMotion uses VM-VirsualBox to create virstual devices with a linux based operating system on your machine.

To solve this problem, you can download [Arm Translation Installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24076795/1638739), or you can easily try it on a real device and it will work as predicted.

Comment: how i can detect that what library have this problem?

Comment: easily call the library only on some activity, and then try to access this activity within the app after installing it in GenyMotion and then it will give you the line where you include this library, and if AndroidStudio doesn't support even installing the app you can do that using eclipse, and if you don't have eclipse you can easily remove the native libraries one by one and see when AndroidStudio will allow you to install the app. 
After all I think all the native libraries you add would cause this problem.

Comment: so try the solution I mentioned "install Arm Translation"

Answer (score 5):

Alright, so I just had the same problem.

simplest solution was

Uncheck the instant run in File-->Settings-->Build,Execution,Deployment--> Instant Run

Comment: You're a hero dude.